# Need help stopping a javascript fade-in effect from occuring after contact form submitted

Tags: javascript, css

I'm pretty new to posting here. I have a javascript effect to make the screen fade in when first entering the website, but I can not prevent it from happening after a form submission. Is there any easy way to accomplish this?

## HTML

```
<form method="post" action="#contact">
  <input type="hidden" name="hidden" id="hidden" value="Message sent from Jay Gervais Design"/>

<div id="comment">
 <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="First Name"><label for="firstname"></label><br />

 <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="Last Name"><label for="lastname"></label><br />

 <input type="text" name="email" id="email" required="required" Placeholder="E-Mail Address"><label for="email"></label><br />

 <textarea rows="10" cols="30" name="comments" id="comments" Placeholder="Write me a comment"></textarea><label for="comments"></label><br />

 <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />

</div>
```

## CSS

```
  body {
  padding-top: 50px;
  font-family: 'Josefin Sans', sans-serif;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: 5s opacity;
}
  body.fade-out {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: none;
}
```

## JS

```
    $(function() {
      $('a[href*="#"]:not([href="#"])').click(function() {
        if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
          var target = $(this.hash);
          target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
          if (target.length) {
            $('html, body').animate({
              scrollTop: target.offset().top
            }, 1000);
            return false;
          }
        }
      });
    }); 

/* Fade in */
    document.body.className += 'fade-out';
    $(function() {
      $('body').removeClass('fade-out');
    })
```

Comment: There are several ways to do this. I see some answers to prevent default, but you could also use a cookie that expires after a few minutes, or if using a server side script such as php, you could use your sessions to determine if the page has already loaded at least once that session. You could also use hidden form data, when submitted, the page knows not to run the animation again. There may be more options, but these come to mind quickly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default behavior for the submit button is to reload the page (which will cause your animation to happen again as well). You can avoid this by using

```
  $("form").submit(function(event){
     event.preventDefault();
  }
```

Comment: Thanks mate. This solution worked well, except it caused me to lose my smooth scroll animation after the submit. I edited my post to include both JS code snippets for both effect. I'm not sure how to single one out over the other.

Comment: I'd most likely go with hidden form data to let the page know not to do the animation again.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Answer (score 0):

add this to your code . you need to prevent transition effect on clicking submit button

```
$("input[type='submit']").click(function(event){
  $('body').css("transition", "none");
});
```

Comment: This made no difference to the transition effect.